# Bayesian decision boundary for bivariate uniform distributions

Tags: probability, bayesian, prior, uniform-distribution

I would like an analytical derivation of the Bayesian decision boundary between 2 bivariate uniform distributions. Let me explain with an example. Suppose the two distributions are $$U_1 = 0.25 \text{ if } 0 \le x_1, x_2 \le 2 \text{ else }0$$ and $$U_2 = 0.5 \text{ if } 1 \le x_1 \le 2, 1 \le x2 \le 3 \text{ else }0$$My intuition is the following: the distributions overlap on the square $1 \le x_1,x_2 \le 2$ and $U_2$ is more probable there so it takes it. That is the boundary is
$$\text{sample}(x_1,x_2) \in U_2 \text{ if } x1,x2 > 1
$$
So far I have silently assumed that the priors are equal. If that's not the cases then not many things change. The only difference is that if the prior of $U_1$ is greater than $2/3$ it takes the overlapping square. In other words, the boundary becomes
$$\text{sample}(x_1,x_2) \in U_2 \text{ if } x1,x2 > 2
$$
How do I prove this though?

PS: My question is kinda the 2d version of [this one](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/74312/how-can-we-find-the-decision-boundary-for-two-overlapping-continuous-uniform-dis).

Comment: Sure. I don't think there's something missing anyway. But I have read that on stackexchange sites is a good practice to add similar questions and clarifying the differences in order to not have them wrongfully flagged as duplicate. Perhaps I should add the similar one in the end?

Comment: Oh yes. I would try to fix it.

Comment: @Xi'an How does it look now?

Comment: @Xi'an Given a sample($x_1, x_2$) the Bayesian classifier labels it as category 1 or category 2 depending on which side of the decision boundary it is. I want to formally solve the problem of finding the equation of said boundary.

Answer (score 2):

Since there is no mention of costs associated with decisions, I assume that the Bayesian decision rule is minimizing the average probability of error.

When Hypothesis $H_0$ is true, the observation $(x_1, x_2)$ is uniformly distributed on a square of side $2$ (sides parallel to the axes) and opposite vertices $(0,0)$ and $(2,2)$.

When Hypothesis $H_1$ is true, the observation $(x_1, x_2)$ is uniformly distributed on a rectangle of area $2$ (sides parallel to the axes) and opposite vertices $(1,1)$ and $(2,3)$.

Thus, the *likeliihood ratio* $\displaystyle \Lambda(x_1,x_2) = \frac{f_1(x_1,x_2)}{f_0(x_1,x_2)}$ has value $\displaystyle\frac{0}{0.25} = 0$ when $(x_1,x_2)$ lies in an L-shaped region of area $3$, value $\displaystyle\frac{0.5}{0.25} = 2$ when $(x_1,x_2)$ lies in the square of area $1$ with opposite vertices $(1,1)$ and $(2,2)$, and value $\displaystyle\frac{0.5}{0} = \infty$ $(x_1,x_2)$ lies in the square of area $1$ with opposite vertices $(1,2)$ and $(2,2)$. Now, the Bayesian decision rule compares $\Lambda(x_1,x_2)$ to the threshold $\displaystyle \frac{\pi_0}{\pi_1}$ where $\pi_0$ and $\pi_1 = 1-\pi_0$  are the prior probabilities of $H_0$ and $H_1$, and so it is easy to figure out what the Bayesian decision rule is, and what the corresponding decision boundary is.

Let $\Gamma_0$ and $\Gamma_1$ denote the disjoint regions such that when $(x_1,x_2) \in \Gamma_i$, the *decision* is that $\Gamma_i$ is the true hypothesis.

- If $\displaystyle\pi_0 < \frac 23$ so that $\displaystyle\frac{\pi_0}{\pi_1} < 2$, $\Lambda(x_1,x_2) > \displaystyle\frac{\pi_0}{\pi_1}$ whenever $(x_1,x_2)$ lies in the rectangular region of area $2$ (sides parallel to the axes) and opposite vertices $(1,1)$ and $(2,3)$. Thus, $\Gamma_1$ is this rectangular region, and we have
  \begin{align}\Gamma_1 &= \{(x_1,x_2)\colon x_1 \geq 1, x_2 \geq 1\}\\
  \Gamma_0 &= \{(x_1,x_2)\colon x_1 < 1~ \textbf{or} ~ x_2 < 1\}\end{align}
- If $\displaystyle\pi_0 > \frac 23$ so that
  $\displaystyle\frac{\pi_0}{\pi_1} > 2$, $\Lambda(x_1,x_2) > \displaystyle\frac{\pi_0}{\pi_1}$  whenever $(x_1,x_2)$ lies in the square region of area $1$ (sides parallel to the axes) and opposite vertices $(1,2)$ and $(2,3)$. Thus, $\Gamma_1$ is this square region, and we have
  \begin{align}\Gamma_1 &= \{(x_1,x_2)\colon x_1 \geq 1, x_2 \geq 2\}\\
  \Gamma_0 &= \{(x_1,x_2)\colon x_1 < 2~, x_2 <2\}\end{align}
- If $\pi_0 = \frac 23$ exactly so that $\Lambda(x_1,x_2)$ has value $2$ exactly equal to the threshold for all $(x_1,x_2)$ in the square region of area $1$ with opposite vertices $(1,1)$ and $(2,2)$. In this instance, *the average error probability* is the same regardless of which points in this region we assign to $\Gamma_0$ and which we assign to $\Gamma_1$ !!  So, we arbitrarily choose to assign them all to $\Gamma_0$ resulting in
  \begin{align}\Gamma_1 &= \{(x_1,x_2)\colon x_1 \geq 1, x_2 \geq 2\}\\
  \Gamma_0 &= \{(x_1,x_2)\colon x_1 < 2~, x_2 <2\}\end{align}

If the OP desires, he can massage the above information into a single humongous formula that upon plugging in the values of $\pi_0, \pi_1$ gives the exact decision boundaries directly and thereby amaze his friends and TA.

Comment: I was trying to use the rule $U_1\cdot \text{ prior of } U_1 = U_2\cdot \text{ prior of } U_2$. I understand you are using the same rule before cross multiplying, correct? You are using the boundary as known and figuring out the decision. I agree. The problem is I am trying to have the boundary as unknown and the solve the equation to find what I see in my drawings. It's like when we find out the intersection point in the 1d case. Does it makes sense what I am asking?